# Can I set in Zsh an environment variable just for a subshell or a compound command?

Tags: zsh

I would like to run two commands, x and y, and define an environmentvariable V just for these too. Is there an easy way to do it in zsh? The "bash-like" solution, i.e.

```
(export V=myvalue; x; y)
```

is cumbersome and works only with a subshell, not a compound. However, the following two versions are syntactically invalid:

```
V=myvalue ( x ; y ) # No!
V=myvalue { x ; y } # No!No!No!
```

Comment: In `bash` at least, the `-k` option allows you to put environment modifiers after a command as well as before. `zsh` allows you to execute anonymous functions. I tried `V=myvalue () { echo $V; }`, which produced a parse error, but I don't know if `() { echo $V; } V=myvalue` might work if `zsh` has an equivalent to `bash`'s `-k` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without at least some extra code.

The modification of the environment by prepending variable assignments works only with [*Simple Commands*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines). Meaning that the first word after the variable assignments needs to be the name of a simple (as in "not complex") command. Complex commands include `{ list }` and `( list )` contstructs. (See the [documentation on *Complex Commands*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands) for a complete list)

If you want to modify the environment for a specific list of commands without changing the environment of your current shell, I can think of two ways to achive that

1. As mentioned in the question there is the rather straight-forward solution by runnig a subshell and exporting the variable explicitly:

   ```
   (export V=myvalue; x; y)
   ```
2. You can use `eval` to avoid creating a subshell:

   ```
   V=myvalue eval "x; y"
   V=myvalue eval x\; y
   ```

   This also saves three to four characters compared to the first solution. The main drawback seems to be that completion does not work very well inside the argument list for `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little longer, but not much. You can define a function, then immediately call it as a simple command.

```
f () { x; y; }; V=foo f
```

Or, you could do a local export with an anonymous function:

```
() { local -x V=myvalue; x; y }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. The version with th anonymous function, though it doesn't look nice, would at least be an option, where I really want to avoid creating a subshell ....